# Android Chrome 39 getByteFrequencyData returns 0 array

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I have setup example here - http://jsbin.com/hotovu/2/

On desktop chrome all is good. Android Chrome 39 returns all the arrays to 0,0,0, ... ( on ADB plugin for chrome debug )

Any workaround to make this work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug.  http://crbug.com/419446.  It's not the Analyser, it's the media element.  If you can load it with XHR into a buffer and play it, it will work.