# Audio context not working properly on android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, html5-audio, chromium

I'm having this issue with android (either for android browser or chrome for android): getByteFrequencyData method returns 0 values.

Some say that the Web Audio Api is not supported in android mobile devices (IOS does support it) but I have juste checked this [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api), where it says that chrome 49 support Audio Api.

Some say that it is an old [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=419446)

And some say that the problem comes from the media element, if you can load the media with XHR into a buffer and play it, it will [work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552704/android-chrome-39-getbytefrequencydata-returns-0-array) (I tested but it didn't work)

I'm trying to make an audio visualizer working on android cordova by using Audio APi + Canvas
Any help?

Comment: Are you by chance talking about AudioSpectrumBands  ?

Comment: No, it is juste an audio visualizer for animation, check this link: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/HTML5-audio-and-the-Web-Audio-API-are-BFFs or this link https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Analyser-Bars-Animation-HTML-Audio-API-Tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work, createBuffer() method with two arguments was not working on chrome versions anymore, so I had to use decodeAudioData in order to get the buffer source:

```
// Create AudioContext and buffer source
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
// load in an audio track via XHR and decodeAudioData
function getData() {
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'Test.mp3', true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.onload = function() {
var audioData = request.response;

audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
myBuffer = buffer;   
source.buffer = myBuffer;

analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser(); // AnalyserNode method
canvas = document.getElementById('CanvasDiv');
canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);

frameLooper(); 
},
function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.err});
}
request.send();
}
function frameLooper(){
ionic.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper); //You can use window instead of ionic
fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
canvasContext.fillStyle = '#00CCFF'; // Color of the bars
bars = 100;

for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
    bar_x = i * 3;
    bar_width = 2;
    bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
    //  fillRect( x, y, width, height ) // Explanation of the parameters below
    canvasContext.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
}
}
getData();
var audio = document.getElementById('audioTagId');
Callback = function(){
        source.start();
    }
document.getElementById("PlayButton").addEventListener("click", Callback);
```